# In Kotlin, how does GSON.fromJson(...) manage to mutate a read-only field of an existing object?

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection, gson, readonly

In Kotlin, how can an instance's read-only `val` field be mutated?

In the following Kotlin code, `gson.fromJson(...)` gets a `Thing(0)` from the `InstanceCreator` and somehow manages to mutate `value` from `0` to `1`, then return that object. How?

```
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import com.google.gson.InstanceCreator

class Thing(val value: Int)

fun main() {
    val creator = InstanceCreator { Thing(0) }
    val gson = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Thing::class.java, creator).create()
    val thing = gson.fromJson("""{"value":1}""", Thing::class.java)
    println(thing.value) // 1
}
```

I verified that the object returned by `gson.fromJson(...)` is the same object provided by the `InstanceCreator`, so it's not creating a new instance based on the one provided by the `InstanceCreator`.

I also tried setting `value` using reflection, but didn't find a way. There was no setter available on the `val` field.

Comment: Also note that you can change [`final` fields at runtime using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3301720/5515060)

Comment: It's because GSON is a java reflection based library that doesn't "play nice" with Kotlin - it can initialize non nullable fields as nulls and isn't aware of default values either. For new projects in Kotlin you should consider more modern solutions like kotlinx.serialization or moshi.

Comment: Being able to mutate `val`s seems like a benefit for my use case. I'm using an API that's sending me a high rate of JSON structures. I want to deserialize them quickly into objects from an object pool to avoid new allocations and the resulting GC pause. I could make the object fields `var`s, but having them as `val`s enforces read-only elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I also tried setting value using reflection

Well, you can do it if you use Java's reflection API, rather than Kotlin's.

Kotlin `val` properties translates to a private Java field with only a public getter. You can set the private field using reflection. For example:

```
val x = Thing(10)
val valueField = x.javaClass.getDeclaredField("value")
valueField.trySetAccessible()
valueField.setInt(x, 20)
println(x.value)
```

This is probably also what Gson does under the hood.

Comment: That works! I wish I could upvote you twice for the miniscule number of seconds that it took you to respond after I posted this question. StackOverflow even says I can't "accept an answer" for another 2 minutes.